# What's a proven setup to develop OpenCL kernels for JavaCL on Mac OS 10.6?

Tags: java, xcode, netbeans, osx-snow-leopard, opencl

Developing OpenCL kernels for the use within JavaCL is a bit of a nuisance using my current setup.

I'm quite happy with NetBeans 6.9.1 for the Java side of things. The maven project setup is painless and everything works as expected.
However, I can't get NetBeans to play nice with CL files within maven projects. Code completion doesn't work and there are error warnings all over the C code, even when providing a working and proven kernel.

How do you develop CL kernels? In a separate C(++) project in NetBeans? Using Xcode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simple image-transforming kernels, you can use JavaCL's new [image transform kernels editor demo](http://code.google.com/p/javacl/wiki/SamplesAndDemos#Image_Transform_Kernels_Editor) (lets you edit your kernel and run it with F5)

Comment: I take it that for more complex kernels a C project makes the most sense, right?

Comment: A C project does not make more sense, there are two separate programs playing here : the host program and the OpenCL kernels. For the kernels, it's better to have an OpenCL-aware editor (I use jEdit, which has no specific support but is ok for C in general), but for the host program Java is easier than C. Here is an example of a C host program : http://bit.ly/dNG3DI and its JavaCL port : http://bit.ly/h384Rz (JavaCL host code is shorter and IDE-friendly for exact same functionality, with OpenCL code strictly unchanged)